# Log requests on inexistent resources on API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I see requests made to a non created endpoint, provided by AWS API Gateway?
I.E: On my API gateway I had only the /customers resource (visible on cloudwatch). But for some reason I want to know if users are making requests to any other endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this thread.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=805138#805138

"
Unfortunately, API Gateway doesn't provide access logs for the customer. I will create a feature request on API Gateway side, and API Gateway will consider prioritizing this request, but I cannot provide the ETA for this. As the workaround, you can create a proxy resource with a mock integration at the same level as your other resources, and you will be able to see the logs of the requests that are hitting the wrong resources.
"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway now supports access logs. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-access-logging/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
no-endpoint:
  description: catch all non-existent enpoints with 404 - must be last 
  http
  handler: src/functions/api-controller.noEndpoint
  events:
  - http:
      path: /{proxy+}
      method: any
      cors: true
```

then in the `noEndpoint` handler log out to CloudWatch logs or whatever logging service you would like to use.

**NOTE:** this must be the last **http** function in your template, otherwise it will catch **ALL** http requests.

proxy+ docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html